# Retrieving rows from DataTable Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to save the row that was selected as an array or some other indexable object. But, I just don't seem to get how to do this.

Here is the code. The line giving me trouble is `output$rowData <- renderText({input$table1[s]})`

```
fluidPage(

   title = " Nanoproject",

   h1("Peak Table and Views"),

   # first row will contain the peak table and peak view 
   fluidRow(
   # give the table half of the page
      column(6, dataTableOutput('table1'), height = 2500),

   #give the other half of the page to the images
      column(6 , 
       imageOutput("image1",width = "auto",height = "auto"),
       htmlOutput("rowData")
   )

server.R

# prompt user to select the peak table file
writeLines("Please select the peaks file")
peaksPath = file.choose()

# read the tsv file 
peaksTable = read.csv(peaksPath , header = TRUE , row.names = NULL , sep = "\t")

server = function(input, output) {
    output$table1 = renderDataTable({
    # the peak table 
    datatable(peaksTable,
          # when rowname is false each row does not have a numeric # associated with it 
          rownames = TRUE,
          # specify the name of the column headers
          colnames = c("Seqnames", "Start", "End","Width","Strand","P","Q","Effectsize",
                       "FDR","Keep","Gene_name","Gene.nearest","Count","Count.pred",
                       "Coverage","Local.mut.density","Base.context.GC","Tn.Context.TpC",
                       "Tn.context.CpG","Dnase","Activechrom","Hetchrom","Rept"),
          # make the table scrollable (horizontally)
          options = list(scrollX = TRUE))

},
escape = FALSE)

output$image1 <- renderImage({

# save which row was selected
s = input$table1_rows_selected

# output the data of the row that was selected
output$rowData <- renderText({input$table1[s]})

#output$rowsSelected <- renderText({s})
list(src=paste0(imagePath,"/peak" , s,".png"),width=700,height=2500)},deleteFile=FALSE)
```

Comment: What kind of troubles?

Comment: Read the help page. Generally `cat` is used for its side-effect and returns NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input$tableId_rows_selected` returns the indices of the rows of the table that are selected.

In your case, you should subset `peakTable` to get the data of the selected rows.

You could try:

```
output$rowData <- renderText({peakTable[s,]})
```

`input$table1` does not hold the table you display in `output$table1`

Comment: I tried that but, I get an error **Error in `[.data.frame`(peaksTable, s) : undefined columns selected**

Comment: I get another error **argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'**

Comment: why are you using `renderText` in this case? `peakTable[s,]` is a data frame so you should use `renderTable` and `tableOutput` if you want to show it in your app. `cat` is run on whatever is in the `renderText` function, and a dataframe is not handled by it.

Comment: why is the comma included. Is that because the comma indicates I would like the row and not the column.

Comment: That's how you subset dataframes. Whatever is before the comma selects rows, whatever is after selects columns, if you put nothing after it selects all columns. See [this](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html)